# Cookie sharing between server/client in NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, cookies, next.js

Let's say you have a standalone server that acts as your data layer and then a Next.js app that's sole purpose is to server-side render the React and occasionally prefetch data from getServerSideProps. Beyond that, most interactions happen between the browser-side client and the standalone server directly (trying to avoid an unnecessary Next.js middleman / cold starts). Now if I'm trying to set an auth token via cookies, is there an elegant way to effectively share that cookie between Next.js and the client, so that the client is authenticated on requests, but also the Next.js getServerSideProps functions?

I'm wondering if I need to have a singular /api/login Next.js serverless function that just acts as a "I'll take the cookie for myself and also pass it right along to you (the client)"

Does this all make sense? In my case the standalone server is built on NestJS. I could use a tool like [react-ssr](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/react-ssr) to server side render everything, and that might be a good solution since almost every page has blocking data requirements, but I'm trying to understand my options, and it seems like this is probably a commonly faced issue with frameworks like Next.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to set cookies directly from the renderer.
Then all you need to do is get your cookie from `req.headers.cookie`.

```js
import Cookie from "js-cookie";

function Index() {
 
  function setCookie() {
    Cookie.set("yourCookieName", "yourCookieValue");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setCookie}>set cookie</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  console.log(req.headers.cookie)
  return { props: {} }
}

export default Index;
```